# 1978 Ford 302 is using a lot of water

Tags: ford, coolant, cooling-system

My 1978 Ford 302 is using a lot of water. There is no oil in the water or no water in the oil and I cant find any leaks.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are either leaking it or burning it.  If you are burning it, you should be able to smell coolant in the exhaust.

Common places for coolant leaks: Radiator, Hoses, Heater core (and valve), Water pump (bearing, and gasket surfaces), Thermostat (gasket surface), Head Gasket, and the Intake manifold gasket

Most of these will show a leak/wet spot.  The intake manifold gasket can leak into the valley between the cylinder banks.  The head gasket can blow between the cylinder and a coolant port.  This will usually lead to bubbling in the radiator when the engine is running.  You would likely be able to see water on the spark plug after the engine has been sitting.

Some tools:

Radiator pressure tester - pressurize the radiator to ~14psi.  watch and listen for leaks.  The faster it looses pressure, the faster the leak.

Compression tester - this will let you know if you have a blown head gasket.